How can I dynamically add an event listener to multiple elements in JavaScript?
I'm working on a project where I need to dynamically add event listeners to multiple elements. The elements are generated dynamically from an API response, so they aren't present in the DOM at the initial page load.
Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:
const container = document.getElementById("container");

const elements = ["Button 1", "Button 2", "Button 3"];
elements.forEach((text) => {
  const button = document.createElement("button");
  button.textContent = text;
  container.appendChild(button);
});

// Adding event listener (this isn't working as expected)
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
buttons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    alert("Button clicked");
  });
});`

The event listeners don't seem to work properly. What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this issue? Should I be using event delegation or some other technique?

"Should I be using event delegation" - what happened when you used Event Delegation?

"The event listeners don't seem to work properly." What makes you think this? You haven't provided your html, but if I make up a simple document, it seems to work.

@mykaf I suspect the relevant part is: The elements are generated dynamically from an API response, so they aren't present in the DOM at the initial page load
